# JS relationshipQuery not returning multiple selected features

Tags: arcgis-server, development, javascript

This is my first time posting a question here.

I am working on a map application using ArcGIS Server 10 with Javascript API 2.1 and I am trying to figure out why I cannot return multiple selected features, within a FeatureLayer, with related SDE data to a dataGrid using the relationshipQuery task.

I am able to return one selected feature to the dataGrid showing the related data, but when I select more than one feature, only one of those features are returned to the dataGrid with associated related data.  For testing purpose, when I take out the relationshipQuery task from my script, all selected features are returned to the dataGrid, but of course without the related data.

Has anyone run into this before and have a solution?  Thanks for your help!

Trent

My code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples on iOS devices-->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Test - Selection Box</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.1/js/dojo/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.1/js/dojo/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.1/js/dojo/dojox/grid/resources/SoriaGrid.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
}
  .soria .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell   {
    color:peru !important;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    djConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true
    }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.dijit"); // optimize: load dijit layer
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
    dojo.require("esri.map");
    dojo.require("esri.toolbars.draw");
    dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");
    dojo.require("esri.tasks.query");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

    var map, toolbar, featureLayer, grid;

    function init() {

        var initialExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": -107.75, "ymin": 30, "xmax": -105, "ymax": 40, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 4269} });
        var map = new esri.Map("map", { extent: esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(initialExtent), slider: true, nav: true });

        dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', function (map) {
            //initialize the toolbar
            toolBar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
            dojo.connect(toolBar, "onDrawEnd", onDrawEnd);
            dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', resizeMap);
        });

        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");

        var imageParams = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
        imageParams.layerIds = [0];
        imageParams.layerOption = esri.layers.ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
        var dynamicLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://gis1ace/ArcGIS10/rest/services/MRG_Point/MapServer", { imageParameters: imageParams });

        featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://gis1ace/ArcGIS10/rest/services/MRG_Point/MapServer/0", {
            mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });

        featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(8).setColor(new dojo.Color([160, 214, 238])));        

        /*var selectionSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 255, 0, 0.5]));
        selectionSymbol.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol("dashdot", new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0]), 2));
        featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);*/

        map.addLayer(basemap);
        map.addLayer(dynamicLayer);
        map.addLayer(featureLayer);

        dojo.connect(featureLayer, "onSelectionComplete", findRelatedRecords);

    }

    // select features using toolbar and build query
    function onDrawEnd(extent) {
        toolBar.deactivate();
        //select features within the draw extent
        var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.geometry = extent;
        //execute query
        featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
        }

        //Relationship query
        function findRelatedRecords(records) {                
                var relatedDocQuery = new esri.tasks.RelationshipQuery();
                relatedDocQuery.outFields = ["*"];
                relatedDocQuery.relationshipId = 1;
                relatedDocQuery.objectIds = [records[0].attributes.OBJECTID];
                featureLayer.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedDocQuery, function (relatedRecords) {
                    var fset = relatedRecords[records[0].attributes.OBJECTID];                        
                    var items = dojo.map(fset.features, function (feature) {                            
                        return feature.attributes;
                    });

                    //Create data object to be used in store
                    var data = {
                        identifier: "OBJECTID",  //This field needs to have unique values
                        label: "OBJECTID", //Name field for display. Not pertinent to a grid but may be used elsewhere.
                        items: items
                    };

                    //Create data store and bind to grid.
                    store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: data });
                    grid.setStore(store);
                    grid.setQuery({ OBJECTID: '*' });
                });

        }

     function resizeMap() {
         //resize the map when the browser resizes
         var resizeTimer;
         clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
         resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
             map.resize();
             map.reposition();
         }, 500);
     }

   dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
</head>

<body class="soria">
<div id="mainWindow" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="true" style="width:600px; height:700px;">
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">
  <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="toolBar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.EXTENT);">Select Layer</button>
  <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="toolBar.deactivate();featureLayer.clearSelection();">Clear Selection</button><br />
</div>
<div id="map" region="center" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="border:1px solid #000;"></div>
</div>
<div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="bottom" style="height:150px; width="100%;"">
    <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsid="grid" id="grid" rowSelector="20px" selectionMode="none">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th field="FeatureID">Feature ID</th>
          <th field="Title" width="25%">Title</th>
          <th field="FileName" width="10%">File Name</th>
          <th field="Description" width="100%">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

edit -- Here's how I added the suggested code:

```
function findRelatedRecords(records) {
        var relatedDocQuery = new esri.tasks.RelationshipQuery();
        var queryIds = dojo.map(records, function (rec) { return rec.attributes.OBJECTID });
        relatedDocQuery.outFields = ["*"];
        relatedDocQuery.relationshipId = 1;
        relatedDocQuery.objectIds = [queryIds];
        featureLayer.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedDocQuery, function (relatedRecords) {
            var fset = relatedRecords[queryIds];
            var items = dojo.map(fset.features, function (feature) {
                return feature.attributes;
            });
```

Comment: dojo.map() returns and array so you shouldn't need to surround queryIds with brackets. Try:  relatedDocQuery.objectIds = queryIds;

Comment: Updated the code with your suggestion and yeah, that makes total sense.  Debugging with Breakpoints, the issue seems to be in the relatedRecords function. More specifically with this line of code: var fset = relatedRecords[queryIds];  when passing multiple OBJECTID's.  Returning one is no problem, but the code seems to break at the fset variable.  Again, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
relatedDocQuery.objectIds = [records[0].attributes.OBJECTID];
```

Looks you're only sending a single ID in your relationship query. Try generating an array of IDs with something like:

```
var queryIds = dojo.map(records, function(rec) { return rec.attributes.OBJECID });
```

Then use queryIds as your relatedDocQuery.objectIds.

Comment: Glad to help! And welcome to the site!

Comment: I added the suggested code, but only one record is still being returned.  Maybe I added the code incorrectly?  I'm still a little green when comes to JS.

Comment: What's getting sent to your server as the relatedDocQuery.objectIds? Can you take a look at the request via Firebug?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Firebug because I am remoting in on another server housing this project, and their server is only using IE. I could fire up IE's Developer Tools, but not too familiar with their debugging IDE.  I'll see what I can come up with though.

Comment: Okay, it looks like multiple Ids are being returned.  I think the problem is passing the multiple Ids to the dataGrid.  Still working through the debugger.  Thanks!